# Align background image horizontally with text using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to follow this UI mockup:[image: mockup] and I'm using Bootstrap 3. Below is my HTML markup and CSS.

```css
#game-configuration .subtitle-icon {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#game-configuration .subtitle-icon .icon {
  height: 100px;
  width: 130px;
}

#game-configuration .subtitle-icon .description {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="subtitle-icon clearfix">
            <div class="icon test-icon pull-left">
            </div>
            <p class="description">Test Gamelift with our Sample game </p>
          </div>
```

However my view ends up looking like [image]

The padding-top I'm adding to the description p tag feels like a hack, and it doesn't align perfectly with the mockup. What's the best way to achieve the top and left padding for the description? Should I use Bootstrap's grid system to create a nested row and column instead of adding more padding-top and padding-left to the description?

Comment: Have you tried bootstrap margin or padding spacing

Comment: can you give us working example of it

Answer (score 0):

You can do with new CSS3 Feature called `flexbox`

```css
.image_block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_block">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pvmCbcW.jpg" alt="" width="100">
  <p>Hi im nisharg shah, welcome to stackoverflow</p>
</div>
```